# Is there any legal issue for copying javascript code to website

Tags: copy-protection

I am making one website and i want to use mortgage repayment calculator. I have seen many real estate sites using that. I want to know that i copy their `javascript calculator` code and style my form differently , will that be an legal issue there

Comment: Don't ask random people on the Internet. Ask a lawyer - preferably one who knows about copyright etc.

Comment: 1) Ask the person who wrote it - or 2) for something common like this, spend 5 seconds looking for [one that comes with no such issues attached](http://www.hypergurl.com/calculator.html).

Comment: @ChrisF I would usually say ask a lawyer, because stuff can become tedious quite fast with law and we are not specialists. But in this case, the answer is so obvious that even a devellopper should know the answer. No, unless explicitly said otherwise - in this case, ask a lawyer because it can be no anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter what programming language is used. The law doesn't have exceptions for Javascript. All code is copyrighted equally.